# Taking the average of bottom n percent in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of data in excel that I need to take the average of the bottom 10% of. My data reads:

```
    1
    2 
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9 
    10
```

so the average of the bottom 30% would be - (1+2+3)/3 = 2. Is there a way to automate this in excel where all I have to do is give it what percent I want and it gives me the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler version: no Array Formula or Indirect required

Assuming data in column `A`, and required percentage in cell `B1` (as a decimal)

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,"<="&SMALL(A:A,COUNT(A:A)*B1))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for when you say 'where all I have to do is give it what percent I want and it gives me the answer', but you could perhaps try `AVERAGEIF`:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A10,"<="&COUNTA(A1:A10)*0.3)
```

Assuming that the data is in the range `A1:A10`. You can have a reference for the 0.3 for the percentage.

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A10,"<="&COUNTA(A1:A10)*B1)
```

If you put the percentage in `B1`, then the formula will change accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in A1:A10, and your desired % is in B1:

```
=AVERAGE(SMALL(A1:A10,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(B1*COUNT(A1:A10))))))
```

**Note!** This is an Array Formula! That means that you have to enter into the formula bar at the top (not in the cell), and press **ctrl shift enter** when you're done.

This will wrap the formula in these { }, so you'll know you did it right. Typing them in does not work, you have to ctrl+alt+enter!

**How does it work?**

```
ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(B1*COUNT(A1:A10))))
```

The Count checks how many items you have in your list, so it knows how many numbers it will need to average. Let's say B1 is 40%.

40% of 10 items is 4, but 40% of 20 is 8.

Since it's 10 entries long, we'll creating an "array", a series of numbers from 1 to 4 (40%).

`*SMALL(A1:A10*`

SMALL finds the *n*th smallest number in a range. With our array of 1 to 4, it will find the lowest 4 entries.

```
AVERAGE(
```

Then we average the result :)